# What is the probability of the absolute value of the difference being 2?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let there be a set A ,where A = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and we are to choose a two member subset {k,m} from A such that k,m are elements of A

What is the probability that |k-m| = 2 ?

Comment: Answer these questions : Fixing $k$, how many choices of $m$ do you have? Does that depend on $k$?

Comment: Questions should be self contained and not a continuation of the title/subject. Please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ All possible two member subsets: combination of $10$ digits taken $2$ at a time.

$2)$ All possible two member subsets satisfying $|k-m|=2: \{0,2\}, \{1,3\}, \cdots, \{7,9\}.$

$3)$ The probability is to divide $2)$ by $1)$ to get $8/45$.

Note: $\{0,2\}=\{2,0\}$. If insisted on distinct $k$ and $m$, then $1)$ permutation, $2)$ twice more, $3)$ the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that the members in set $A$ are all of the integers between 0 and 9 inclusive

Thus we are being asked for the probability of selecting two members in the list that are seperated by one other member.

So how many ways are there to do this?   How many equally-likely ways are there to select *any* two from the ten members?   Divide and calculate.